# In R how to get a percentage of a vector row by row

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with two columns. I would like to get a rolling percentage row by row that resets by sub.

```
library(data.table)
sub <-c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C")
n<-c(0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1)

df <- data.table(sub,n )

    sub n
 1:   A 0
 2:   A 1
 3:   A 1
 4:   A 1
 5:   B 0
 6:   B 1
 7:   B 0
 8:   B 1
 9:   C 0
10:   C 1
11:   C 0
12:   C 1
```

What I need it to look like:

```
    sub n rolling_percentage
 1:   A 0               0.00
 2:   A 1               0.50
 3:   A 1               0.66
 4:   A 1               0.75
 5:   B 0               0.00
 6:   B 1               0.50
 7:   B 0               0.33
 8:   B 1               0.50
 9:   C 0               0.00
10:   C 1               0.50
11:   C 0               0.33
12:   C 1               0.50
```

what I have tried :
`df$rolling_percentage= 100*cumsum(df$n)/sum(df1$n)`
But that gives me this

```
    sub n rolling_percentage
 1:   A 0            0.00000
 2:   A 1           14.28571
 3:   A 1           28.57143
 4:   A 1           42.85714
 5:   B 0           42.85714
 6:   B 1           57.14286
 7:   B 0           57.14286
 8:   B 1           71.42857
 9:   C 0           71.42857
10:   C 1           85.71429
11:   C 0           85.71429
12:   C 1          100.00000
```

I need it to reset every time the df$sub changes.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Based on your question, shouldn't `rolling_percentage = c(0, 33.3, 66.6, 100)` for `sub = A`?

Comment: Great question, the rolling percentage is row by row based on sub. Maybe cumulative is the wrong word.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can divide the cumulative sum of `n` with the row number in the group.

```
library(data.table)
df[, rolling_percentage := cumsum(n)/seq_len(.N), sub]
df

#    sub n rolling_percentage
# 1:   A 0               0.00
# 2:   A 1               0.50
# 3:   A 1               0.67
# 4:   A 1               0.75
# 5:   B 0               0.00
# 6:   B 1               0.50
# 7:   B 0               0.33
# 8:   B 1               0.50
# 9:   C 0               0.00
#10:   C 1               0.50
#11:   C 0               0.33
#12:   C 1               0.50
```

---

`dplyr` has a special function `cummean` for this purpose.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(sub) %>% mutate(rolling_percentage = cummean(n))
```